# Implicitly called task / function on python Fabric startup?

Tags: python, fabric

There are a few environment variables I need to set in Fabric each invocation and so far I'm doing something like:

```
env['FOO'] = 'one'

@task
def one():
    env['FOO'] = 'one'
    print(cyan('Using FOO %s' % env['FOO']))

@task
def two():
    env['FOO'] = 'two'
    print(cyan('Using FOO %s' % env['FOO']))

@task
def run():
    with shell_env(FOO=env['FOO']):
    local(...)

# more tasks that have the same pattern as run() above
```

Firstly, I would like to provide a better mechanism of auto setting FOO if neither 'one' or 'two' is invoked.  Perhaps there's some implicit "set-up" task or method that is invoked every Fabric run?

Also, there are actually more FOO settings (10 in total), is there a generic task/method called when a task isn't found?  Something like a catch-all like:

```
def catchall(name, *args, **kwargs):
    if name in ['one', 'two', ...]:
        env['FOO'] = name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your task a subclass of a custom class with certain attributes that are passed as parameters:

```
from fabric.api import task
from fabric.tasks import Task

class CustomTask(Task):
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomTask, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.func = func
        self.foo = "one"

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(self.foo, *args, **kwargs)

@task(task_class=CustomTask)
def one(foo):
    print(cyan('Using FOO %s' % foo))
```

Comment: It's strange but for some reason the custom task is being called implicitly and doubly if I specify a task inherited by custom task as an argument to fab