# Call a task/function on every fab invocation

Tags: fabric

I am currently working on a fabric file for deployment and I would like to have one task or function that is always called, regardless of the fab tasks that were given in the command line.

This function is supposed to set some default values in the environment and should be called **after** the host list has been updated according to the -H parameter, but **before** any "real" tasks are performed.

Is this possible, or do I have to call this function manually at the beginning of every task?

**Example:**

```
import from fabric.api import local, settings, abort, run, lcd, cd, env, task

def set_defaults():
    if 'host1' in env.hosts:
        env.user = 'default_user'

def deploy():
    print 'deploy'
```

And `fab -H host1 deploy` should call `set_defaults` first and then `deploy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [plans](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/452) to introduce a feature for this in fabric 2.
With fabric 1 you could create a [subclass of a custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650812/implicitly-called-task-function-on-python-fabric-startup).